# polymer : unable initialize project from a template

Tags: node.js, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying learn with my first polymer app and I am stuck.

I started from here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up

I installed the Polymer CLI successfully.
Now, When I am trying to initialize project from a template, it shows following log in my cmd:

```
C:\Users\chint\Desktop\polymer-app>polymer init app-drawer-template
info:    Running template app-drawer-template
info:    Downloading latest release of Polymer/app-drawer-template
info:    Unpacking template files
info:    Finished writing template files

I'm all done. Running bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present
```

And when I checked, my polymer-app folder was empty. Nothing got dowloaded.

Can anyone please help me with it ?

**PS:** my node.js version is 6.1.0

Answer (score 4):

That seems to be a little bug on Windows, Ubuntu worked for me.

[This](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/187) Issue suggests that a Node.js update to 6.2 would fix the problem.

In case it does not:

To start the app-drawer-template or the shop app you can also simply clone them from GitHub with

```
git clone https://github.com/Polymer/app-drawer-template.git
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/Polymer/shop.git
```

After that do a `bower install` in the downloaded directory and run the app with `polymer serve`

Comment: Ok Eric. Thanks. Voted for useful.

Comment: @ChintanSoni Please accept the answer if it answers your question :-)